# How would I disable a function by clicking on TextInput

Tags: react-native

I have this class for blinking text:

```
class BlinkerFluid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isShowingText: true,
      TextInputName = ''
    };

    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(previousState => {
        return { isShowingText: !previousState.isShowingText };
      });
    }, 700);
  }
  render () {
    let display = this.state.isShowingText ? this.props.text : '   ';
    return (
      <Text style={styles.other}>{display}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

And this class to render the blinking text:

```
 export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'x' };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.other}>$ root | &gt; </Text>
      <BlinkerFluid text=' _' />
      <TextInput style={styles.lol}
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
      value={this.state.text}
    />
  </View>

);
}
}
```

I want to be able to stop the blinking of the text when I click on the TextInput prop and/or write to it.
How would I go about doing that?
I've been trying to search for an answer on my own, read the docs, but nothing has helped.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like the below code snippet (I've only included the code for `App`. You can implement the `paused` functionality in the `BlinkerFluid` however you want.

Basically, I'm storing in the state whether the blinker should be paused or not, then passing that value through to the `BlinkerFluid` component as a prop. You can set the `pauseBlinker` state easily, perhaps on `onChangeText` as in the example, or on press of a `TouchableOpacity` element etc.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: 'x',
      pauseBlinker: false,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.other}>$ root | &gt; </Text>
        <BlinkerFluid text=' _' paused={this.state.pauseBlinker} />
        <TextInput style={styles.lol}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text, pauseBlinker: true, })}
        value={this.state.text}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```